# Spring 3.0.4 Not Executing Scheduled-Task Properly

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to have a method execute every 10 seconds. However, it only executes once and then never executes again. Here is my configuration

```
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="somePollerClass" method="pollMethod" cron="*/10 * * * * *"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I took the cron configuration from the spring [CronSequenceGenerator javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) page. I don't understand why it isn't executing every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This was an environmental issue where some of my files were not being updated. The above configuration functions properly.